# normalized two different arrays to be equal in length

Tags: python

I have two arrays

```
x = [5, 8, 7, 9]
```

and

```
y = [7, 5, 6, 8, 6]
```

I want to make them in equal length by applaying linear mapping between them and their corrspending time indexes. In a sense that I force the longer time series to shrink to the length of the shorter time series and the shorter series to expand to the length of the longer series. Is there any function in python to do this? Or any algorithm?

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: can you explain "by applying linear mapping between them and their indexes"?

Comment: Don't overestimate your prose ;-) Show the desired output.

Comment: Take a random element from the longer and append it to the shorter until their lengths differ by at most 1.

Comment: @JonSG can you explain more you idea please?

Comment: If you give a more complete example of the data and the result you seek I can. At the moment I would start with `shorter.append(longer.pop(random.randint(0, len(longer)-1)))`

Comment: I imagine you do it with dynamic programming. Construct a matrix with your x values down the left, y across the top. The contents of your matrix are (x-y)^2. You have to get from top left of the matrix to bottom right, and you are only allowed to move downward a maximum of 1 and/or rightward a maximum of 1 at each stage. Minimise the sum of matrix elements from top left to bottom right. Visually, it looks like the (x,y) sequence is (5,7), (5,5), (5,6), (8,8), (7,6), (9,6) or, in terms of indices, (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,3), (2,4), (3,4). Is that what you want?

Comment: @lastchance how can i stretch the shorter sequence then to be equal to the longer?

Comment: If that time-warping is what you want then the sequences are (both) increased in length by REPEATS (because you must maintain continuity). The first sequence becomes [5,5,5,8,7,9] and the second becomes [7,5,6,8,6,6]. You are aiming to minimise the squared difference between them. Of course, this may not be what you want: your question is not clear.

Comment: @lastchance how can i code this in python please?

Comment: You had better say whether that is your intended output first. It's very difficult to tell from your question.

Comment: @lastchance exactely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is known as "time-warping" - you can google that.

The aim is to stretch the sequences so that individual "features" line up. Mathematically, one way (but not the only one) of doing that is to minimise the sum of squared differences (sum (x[i]-y[i])<sup>2</sup>) in stretched sequences by repeating elements where necessary.

To do this you can set the items out in a matrix/table, where the x values go down the left and the y values across the top. The elements of the matrix are the squared differences (of x at the left and y at the top).
For your given sequences it would look like this:

```
      7   5   6   8   6
------------------------
5 |   4   0   1   9   1
8 |   1   9   4   0   4
7 |   0   4   1   1   1
9 |   4  16   9   1   9
```

Now you need the path with the smallest sum of weights from top-left (start of the sequences) to
bottom-right (end of the sequences). One way to do this is by dynamic programming. At each move you are only
allowed to move a maximum of one point along each sequence, so within the matrix you only have three choices, diagrammatically

```
\  |
 \ |
-- new
```

i.e. S<sub>ij</sub> = w<sub>ij</sub> + min( S<sub>i-1,j</sub>, S<sub>i-1,j-1</sub>, S<sub>i,j-1</sub> ) where w<sub>ij</sub> is the weight at the point and S<sub>ij</sub> is the sum of weights up to that point. You will also need to keep track of your path, and I do that in the code below by creating a new Element type that includes the previous point.

The two possible optimal paths for your sequences are shown below. (In general, there may be several such optimals.)

```
      7   5   6   8   6                      7   5   6   8   6
------------------------               ------------------------
5 |   4   0   1                        5 |   4   0   1
8 |               0                    8 |               0
7 |                   1                7 |               1
9 |                   9                9 |                   9
```

Where there is equality by two different routes you can extend the code below to choose the one with the least elements. However, that won't make any difference here.

I would probably make a better job of this in c++ or fortran, but feel free to improve the python code below.

```
class Element:
   iPrev, jPrev = -1, -1
   weight = 0
   pathWeight = 0
   pathLength = 1
   def __init__( self, i, j, w, pw, pl ):
      self.iPrev, self.jPrev, self.weight, self.pathWeight, self.pathLength = i, j, w, pw, pl

def timeWarp( x, y ):
   nx, ny = len( x ), len( y )

   # Set up a matrix of weights
   M = [[]]
   for i in range( nx ):
      M.append( [] )
      for j in range( ny ):
         weight = ( x[i] - y[j] ) ** 2
         M[i].append( Element( -1, -1, weight, weight, 1 ) )

   # Update left and top edges
   for i in range( 1, nx ):
      prev = M[i-1][0]
      curr = M[i][0].weight
      M[i][0] = Element( i - 1, 0, curr, prev.pathWeight + curr, prev.pathLength + 1 )
   for j in range( 1, ny ):
      prev = M[0][j-1]
      curr = M[0][j].weight
      M[0][j] = Element( 0, j - 1, curr, prev.pathWeight + curr, prev.pathLength + 1 )

   # Dynamic programming to minimise sum of squared differences
   for i in range( 1, nx ):
      for j in range( 1, ny ):
         curr = M[i][j].weight
         left, abov, diag = M[i][j-1], M[i-1][j], M[i-1][j-1]
         if diag.pathWeight <= abov.pathWeight:
            if diag.pathWeight <= left.pathWeight: M[i][j] = Element( i - 1, j - 1, curr, diag.pathWeight + curr, diag.pathLength + 1 )
            else:                                  M[i][j] = Element( i    , j - 1, curr, left.pathWeight + curr, left.pathLength + 1 )
         else:
            if abov.pathWeight <= left.pathWeight: M[i][j] = Element( i - 1, j    , curr, abov.pathWeight + curr, abov.pathLength + 1 )
            else:                                  M[i][j] = Element( i    , j - 1, curr, left.pathWeight + curr, left.pathLength + 1 )

   # Find path backwards from end of sequence
   xindices, yindices = [ nx - 1 ], [ ny - 1 ]
   i, j = xindices[-1], yindices[-1]
   while True:
      i, j = M[i][j].iPrev, M[i][j].jPrev
      if i == -1: break
      xindices.append( i )
      yindices.append( j )

   # Then reverse it to the correct direction
   xindices.reverse()
   yindices.reverse()

   return xindices, yindices


########## Driver program #########

x = [ 5, 8, 7, 9 ]
y = [ 7, 5, 6, 8, 6 ]

# Get indices of stretched arrays
xi, yi = timeWarp( x, y )
print( "Index pairs:" )
for i, j in zip( xi, yi ): print( i, j )

# Now create the actual extended sequences
xplus = [ x[i] for i in xi ]
yplus = [ y[i] for i in yi ]
print( "Sequence pairs:" )
for a, b in zip( xplus, yplus ): print( a, b )

######## End driver program #######
```

Output:

```
Index pairs:
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 3
2 3
3 4
Sequence pairs:
5 7
5 5
5 6
8 8
7 8
9 6
```

Comment: how can i display, or return the matrix values please?

Comment: M[i][j].weight would give you the matrix element for x[i], y[j].

Comment: Now if i want to use the output of this function as input of an other function how can i use them?

Comment: The function currently outputs the required indices as lists and prints out the new sequence values. But there’s nothing stopping you putting the stretched sequence values into new lists (e.g., by using list comprehensions) rather than just printing them out. You can use those new lists wherever you like.

Comment: As i'm biginner in python i don't know how to put them in lists

Comment: @lili, I have amended the code to put the stretched sequences into lists ```xplus``` and ```yplus```, using list comprehensions. I think now would be a good time to start learning python properly. Find a good book, or the tutorial at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: this is exactly what i want, but in the code can you show me where and how you have stretch sequneces?

Comment: When M[i][j] is updated (the bunch of if ... else if ... statements in the middle of the code) then it sets the data members iprev and jprev. Unless they are equal to i-1 and j-1, respectively, then you will be repeating either i or j as the next index. These repeats increase the length of the corresponding sequence.

Comment: The code already does that. Note that both arrays can be stretched, it's just that the shorter one gets stretched more, so that the resulting arrays are the same length.

Comment: How can i add my code here for calculation of cost matrix please?